# Can a phone act as computer replacement?

Tags: external-keyboard, external-display, mouse

Given the power of current day smartphones it seems like many could work as basic computer replacements.  In the past Microsoft tried to provide a [display dock to turn a Microsoft Phone into a PC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/accessory/hd-500/). Is there something similar for Android phones?

I guess some of them allow HDMI output, but is the software adapted to work with a keyboard+mouse? Would a phone be able to power/connect to an external hard drive?

Comment: You haven't heard of [Samsung DeX](https://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/apps/samsung-dex/)?

Comment: There is also "Huawei Easy Projection". Together with a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse this also comes close to a desktop.

Comment: As long as an Android device has OTG support, it will support hardware mice and keyboards by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [Samsung Dex](https://www.samsung.com/us/explore/dex/?redir=dex).

What you'll need:

- A Compatible Samsung smartphone.  As of the time of this post, this includes the S8, S9, S10, Note8, and Note9.
- Either the [Dex Pad](https://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/mobile-accessories/phones/dex-pad-ee-m5100tbegus/) or [Dex Station](https://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/mobile-accessories/phones/dex-station---black-ee-mg950tbegus/) to dock your phone and connect it to an external display, mouse, and keyboard.