# Can I turn my Android to Linux desktop?

Tags: linux, external-display

I want to turn my phone into a Linux Desktop when I connect it to an external display but not using screen mirroring (I.e., the external screen is running while phone screen is turned off).

There is something similar to my needs called "Samsung Dex" but I don't have it on my phone.

I found steps to install Linux Distro & open graphical desktop using VNC but never found a way to open it on the external display.

I also found Drivedroid but I don't want neither to run root (hence erase data and lose phone warranty) nor to use a computer as a device resource (CPU, Ram, GPU...).

All googling lead to "turn android to second screen" no matter how I rephrase it.

The only questions that is almost similar to my case are [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4546/376936) & [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208730/can-a-phone-act-as-computer-replacement).

All I am asking for is keywords to search for.

Keywords that I used to search for:

1. Ubuntu for Android: just gives me links to Ubuntu touch; not my question.
2. Docking android: gave me some results for devices that I can buy (like nex book that uses phone or RPI to run a semi-laptop).
3. Android as Linux Desktop: results for "use android as second monitor"

Comment: Android uses an Linux based kernel and some of the core components are Linux based but Android is not a Linux system (compared to other Linux distributions for PC). Especially the UI system is totally different from Linux X/Wayland. Samsung DEX is a proprietary extension of Android by Samsung. As apps can not control an externally connected monitor an OS modification is the only way to get something like a desktop.

Comment: @Robert so you are saying that there is no such thing as an installation of Ubuntu or Kali or Debian (even as emulation) on Android? is my last resort to install something like Ubuntu touch?

Comment: There are emulations but on unrooted devices they don't have a chance to get access to an external display. And on rooted devices I am not sure how much effort is necessary to send the display output through the USB port, assuming the phone hardware has the capability. The main problem is most likely that every phone has a different hardware and you need to directly speak to the hardware.